# Using ConfigSetting Layout Renderer doesn't work as documented

Tags: configuration, nlog

My question relates specifically to this documentation page/wiki
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Since I'm doing exactly what it says but can't get my connection string to be retrieved from my app settings.

The wiki doc shows this code, but does not make it perfectly clear where it needs to be, so this is where I put it in a .NET6 API in Program.cs. If I hardcode the connection string, this all works, so the necessary libraries nlog/extensions/web-aspnetcore/nlog-database are all set and working.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
                    {   // code from docs - does this only work if I use this logger variable to log?
                        var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();                             logging.AddNLog(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    });
            });
}
```

Then in nlog.config I use this; (I also tried using 'name' instead of 'item', not clear on this either, given many other examples use this:

```
connectionString="${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.PostgreSQL}"
```

When I do this, I still get `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`
So I'm wondering if the documentation is not making this clear.

In order to get this to work do I need actually use the `logger` variable in code, for the remainder to work?

I'm not doing this, I use constructor injection via the logging abstractions library - which otherwise works fine.

```
public MyController(ILogger<ActivitiesController> log)
{
    _log = log;
}

[HttpGet("test")]   public async
Task<ActionResult<IList<ADto>>> Table()     {
        _log.LogInformation("Loading something..."); ...
```

Comment: Manual calling `LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()` is only intended for logging before calling `CreateDefaultBuilder`. You should just use `UseNLog()` as it says in the documentation.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6